# Get an element id and generic element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

I have a CSS selector `#menu li {background-color: red;}`.

I want to access its attributes in JavaScript. It's important that I need to access both `#menu` and `li` since `#menu` alone has different attributes. It seems like `getElementById(menu li), QuerySelector and getComputedStyle` are not working in this case.

Is there any other way to achieve that or am I missing something here?

Comment: You should definitely use jquery for this.

Comment: Can you post the full code please?

Comment: you should try `document.querySelectorAll("#menu li")`. This gives you a list of all nodes that you can work on. Or use jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery for this, here the easy code example

```
    //html
            <div id="menu" data-number="123" > 
            </div>
    //jquery
            var menu = $('#menu').attr('data-number');
            console.log(menu);
            //print 123
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery version

https://jsfiddle.net/pn52uvw1/

```
$(".button_1").click(function(){
     alert($("#menu").attr("data-item-id"));
})
$(".button_2").click(function(){
     alert($("#menu li").attr("data-item-id"));
})
```

non jquery version

https://jsfiddle.net/pn52uvw1/2/

```
window.firstFunction =  function(){
    var target = document.getElementById("menu");
    alert(target.getAttribute('data-item-id'));
}

window.secondFunction =  function(){
    var target = document.getElementById("menu").children[0];
    alert(target.getAttribute('data-item-id'));
}
```

but you will need to get rid of that [0] index probably, and use a for or something for multiple li items

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get that css rule's property, you can do like this:

```js
function getStyleFromSelector(selector, styleName) {
    // Get all style elements
    var styles = document.styleSheets;
    var styleIndex = 0, styleCount = styles.length;
    var rules, ruleCount, ruleIndex;
    // Iterate though styles
    for (styleIndex = 0; styleIndex < styleCount; ++styleIndex) {
      
      // Get the css rules under the style.
      rules = styles[styleIndex].rules;
      ruleCount = rules.length;
      for (ruleIndex = 0; ruleIndex < ruleCount; ++ruleIndex) {
        
        // Check if the selector match the one we want
        if (rules[ruleIndex].selectorText === selector) {
          return styleName ? 
              rules[ruleIndex].style.getPropertyValue(styleName) : rules[ruleIndex];
        }
      }
    } 
}

var div = document.getElementById("results");
var result = getStyleFromSelector('#menu li');
console.log(result);
div.innerHTML = 'background-color is : ' + result.style.backgroundColor;
console.log(getStyleFromSelector('#menu li', 'background-color'));
```

```css
#menu li {background-color: red;}
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it without additional Libraries with the following

```
var len = document.querySelectorAll("#menu li").length;
for(i = 0; i<len; i++)
  document.querySelectorAll("#menu li")[i].style.backgroundColor="blue";
```

I also made you (a not very beautiful) jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/gmeewsmz/